# Groovy pretty print XmlSlurper output from HTML?

Tags: html, groovy, xmlslurper

I am using several different versions to do this but all seem to result in this error:

[Fatal Error] :1:171: The prefix "xmlns" cannot be bound to any namespace explicitly; neither can the namespace for "xmlns" be bound to any prefix explicitly.

I load html as:

```
// Load html file
def fis=new FileInputStream("2.html")
def html=new XmlSlurper(new  org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()).parseText(fis.text)
```

Versions I've tried:

http://johnrellis.blogspot.com/2009/08/hmmm_04.html

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
def streamingMarkupBuilder=new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
println XmlUtil.serialize(streamingMarkupBuilder.bind{mkp.yield html})
```

http://old.nabble.com/How-to-print-XmlSlurper%27s-NodeChild-with-indentation--td16857110.html

```
// Output
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.util.XmlNodePrinter
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild

def printNode(NodeChild node) {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    writer << new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
      mkp.declareNamespace('':node[0].namespaceURI())
      mkp.yield node
    }
    new XmlNodePrinter().print(new XmlParser().parseText(writer.toString()))
}
```

Any advice?

Thank you!
Misha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is namespaces. Here is the solution:

```
def saxParser=new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()
saxParser.setFeature('http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces',false)
new XmlSlurper(saxParser).parseText(text)    

import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
println XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
                mkp.yield page
              })
```

Thank you!
Misha

Comment: Not sure if this should be the accepted answer. `XmlUtil.serialize` internally converts the `Writable` returned by `StreamingMarkupBuilder.bind` to a String. This defeats the whole porpose of streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't have an answer but if I use XmlParser then

```
def html=new XmlSlurper(new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()).parseText(somehtml)        
new XmlNodePrinter(preserveWhitespace:true).print(html)
```

Will pretty print.

Also if you get a StreamingMarkupBuilder, you can do:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
println XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    ... make your markup here ...
}
)
```

Misha